# Open external application and close current application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, exit

In my gui project, I need to start another application that updates the application that called the initial update.. if that makes sense.

The only way the secondary program can update the main program is if the main program is closed.

This is what I did:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:update.exe"));
qApp->quit();
```

In the update program I also added a 2 second sleep timer before the update begins just in case. The problem is the main program never closes.

I have replaced qApp->quit() with qApp->exit, QApplication::quit(), QCoreApplication::exit() etc and nothing is closing the main program.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProcess>

qApp->quit();
QProcess::startDetached("update.exe");
```

Comment: The application doesnt close :/

Comment: `qApp->quit();` will work only after `QApplication::exec()` call, I think.

Comment: I added qapplication::exec() right before qApp->quit()and it didnt close. Instead, it only opened update.exe when I closed it manually.

Comment: @mc360pro, yes, because `exec()` blocks while the application is running. Next statements will be called only when you close your application.

Comment: Use `QProcess::startDetached` instead of `exec`.

Comment: startDetached is not a function of QApplication though

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the following (hopefully idea is clear from the source code):

```
// Launches another application after 5 seconds.
class Launcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Launcher()
    {
        QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, SLOT(launch()));
    }
private slots:
    void launch()
    {
        QProcess::startDetached("notepad");
        qApp->quit();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Launcher launcher;

    [..]

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Quick question, how will this close the main program?

Comment: @mc360pro, well, I have updated the code so that it will launch another application after 5 seconds after starting the initial one. The initial app. will be closed than.

Comment: I have to get off atm but I will try this out asap and get back to you :)

Comment: that should work. so in case of the update program, you should pass the path to the calling process to the updater to make shure it can start the same application again when the update is done

Comment: In my case, for some reason I just cant close my application. I commented out anything to do the update program. It just doesn't close.

Comment: @mc360pro, maybe there another event loop running in the same time?

Comment: I do have an event loop running earlier in my program to check for the initial update. How should I close this loop? Im testing with loop::exit()

Comment: Exiting the loop has no change.